# EF Core ValueObject comparison could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ef-core-2.2

I have designed my domain using DDD and EF Core.

Assuming my Entity looks like this:

```
public sealed class ArticleEntity
{
    private ArticleEntity() { }

    public ArticleId Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

And my ArticleId ValueObject looks like this:

```
public sealed class ArticleId
{
    public ArticleId(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; }

    public static bool operator ==(ArticleId obj1, ArticleId obj2)
    {
        return (obj1 is null && obj2 is null)
            || (!(obj1 is null) && obj1.Equals(obj2));
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ArticleId obj1, ArticleId obj2)
    {
        return !(obj1 == obj2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}
```

I get data from Repository using such query:

```
public ArticleEntity Get(ArticleId id)
{
    return _context.Articles
        .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

When I browse through logs, I see entries like this one:

> 20500|WARN|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query|The LINQ expression
>   'where ([a].Id == __id_0) ' could not be translated and will be
>   evaluated locally.

I have already setup a conversion for ArticleId parameter, like this one:

```
builder.Property(a => a.Id)
    .HasConversion(
         id => id.Value,
         value => new ArticleId(value));
```

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Hi.I have a same problem did you get any solutions?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately migrating from EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 3.0 solved the issue.
I cannot find it now but on their GitHub Issue tracker they have mentioned that the issue is fixed in the new release.

For all those facing the same problems - updating EF Core to a newer version should help. If somehow you cannot update the package you could try changing your DB Context to explicitly throw exception when Client-side evaluation occurs and face each issue separately.

Comment: Yes it works for equals operator but you can't use Contains.. i.e. FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.Value.Contains("1235"));